# Including captions in app generated images

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, policy, x-facebook-platform

I am having a doubt regarding the Facebook policies. It is being stated that:

> IV. Application Integration Points
>
> .....
>
> 1. You must not pre-fill any of the fields associated with the following products, unless the user manually generated the content
>      earlier in the workflow: Stream stories (user_message parameter for
>      Facebook.streamPublish and FB.Connect.streamPublish, and message
>      parameter for stream.publish), Photos (caption), Videos (description),
>      Notes (title and content), Links (comment), and Jabber/XMPP.
>
> .....
>   Source: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

And from the [examples & explanation page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/policy/examples_and_explanations/photos/), it says the following for Photos:

> You must not pre-fill Photo captions unless the user manually
>   generated the content earlier in the workflow. These fields are
>   intended for users to express themselves. Pre-filling these fields
>   erodes the authenticity of the user voice.

[image]

So, my question is: I have seen 99% of the apps (that I used), is auto-filling caption field for photos with say, something like: `You can try it by visiting here: http://www.apps.blahblah.com/appname`

Isn't that against the facebook policy ? Or they are not flagged because they are using the extended permissions(`publish_stream`) instead of the `post_actions` ?

If it is not allowed for both the permissions, then my next question is, how would we tell the users viewing the photo, the link to the app so that these audiences can also try the app ?

Also, if possible, I would like to see a small example of the caption that would be generated in the workflow as mentioned here in the policies: `...You must not pre-fill any of the fields associated with the following products, unless the user manually generated the content earlier in the workflow...`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is against policies, but many apps do it nevertheless.

I think a compromise would be to have the user enter their own message, and then just *append* a little link to the end of that before posting it.

As for the example, what exactly would you like to know/see? You have the user put in a message through a text field/input box/whatever, and set that as the message while posting the image.

Comment: Oh! I see. But none of them seems to be flagged. But mine got flagged saying that I shouldn't auto fill the message field! What my app would do is, it would append their name along with a message and then includes the link to the app. That message is a string which is common for all users.

Comment: Got flagged by users reporting it, or automatically? Posting the exact same message for a number of users is a thing that Facebook easily spots, and therefor as I said it’s better to have the user enter their own message, and just _append_ your link to the end of it.

Comment: It seems to be automatic. Ok, let me try what you have suggested. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Currently its forbidden. User should fill the whole caption text. Adding anything to it also is also forbidden.

You can watch the Facebook policy video about pre-filling here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill